# Removing the LF in codeblocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, lf

[image]

How do i remove the LF at the end of each line in code blocks?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe, there should be a way to select file encoding in CodeBlocks?

Comment: LF stand for Line Feed (`\n`) (and CR for Carriage Return `\r`).

Comment: Well i'm new to Code blocks and i haven't opened the settings yet. so i'm not sure where that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Settings → Editor → General Settings tab → Editor Settings tab → uncheck "show end-of-line chars"

Comment: Worked perfectly thank you so much!! i'll accept the answer after 5 mins

Answer (score 0):

CodeLite:
View -> Display EOL (Check/Uncheck)